# $LF/K$ is a finite Galois extension, then $L/K$ isn't necessarily a Galois extension

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

So I have to find a counter example such that:

"$LF/K$ is a finite Galois extension, then $F/K$ isn't necessarily a Galois extension"

Just wanna verify my example, since it's so simple, I think I may made some mistakes. Let $F=\mathbb{Q}$, $L=\mathbb{Q}(\delta_3)$, $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, in which $\delta_3$ is the cube root of unity. Then $LF=\mathbb{Q}(\delta_3,\sqrt[3]{ 2})$ is the splitting field of $x^3-2$. Then $LF/K$ is Galois extension while $F/K$ isn't. Is it right? THank you.

Comment: Yes. $F/K$ isn't Galois because.. And $LF/K$ is the splitting field of $x^3-2$ because..